# Issue with Jquery slideshow

Tags: jquery, slideshow

I stayed up all night just trying to resolve the JQuery slideshow but I am not sure why it is not working as expected. I forgot to snap the example but right now my laptop is not with me, so I will post later in several hours' time, if you need to see the example.

i borrowed plugin's function: http://medienfreunde.com/lab/innerfade/

```
    <script>

                   jQuery.noConflict();
                   $(document).ready( function(){
                   $('li#slider_reel').innerfade({
                   animationtype:'fade',
                   speed: 'slow',
                   timeout: 4000,
                   type: 'sequence',
                   containerheight: '648px'; });

                   });

                   </script>


    <div id="slider_view">
    <div id="slider_reel">

    <ul>
    <li><img src="slide/A.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="slide/B.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="slide/C.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="slide/D.jpg"></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    <!--end reel-->

ul#slider_reel li img{
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 4px;
}


.fade{
    margin-bottom: 2em;
}

.fade p{
    margin-bottom: 2em;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
}
```

The result: all images appear in long vertically order (just like stack or pile to one another). Couldn't figure why it is behaving like this. Thank you in advance for your help

**EDIT**
My apologises. It did have ul and li - i forgot to add them inside. got the same result.

**EDIT II**
I finally got it working. i think i missed some '}' or something and also I replaced the script with actual file instead of href.

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got it working,
http://jsfiddle.net/BceNn/6/

One of the problems:

```
containerheight: '648px'; /*REMOVE THIS SEMICOLON*/ });/*REMOVE THIS SEMICOLON*/
```

EDIT: Here is working code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function(){
    $('#slider_reel').innerfade({
        animationtype:'fade',
        speed: 'slow',
        timeout: 4000,
        type: 'sequence',
        containerheight: '648px' 
    })
});
</script>


    <ul id="slider_reel">
    <li><img src="slide/A.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="slide/B.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="slide/C.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="slide/D.jpg"></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: you mean remove both semicolon? If so, it is still not working.

Comment: already fixed before you posted but thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

fix your selectors there is not ULs nor LIs then try again

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably here, in your CSS:

```
ul#slider_reel li img{
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 4px;
}
```

Copy + pasting code isn't a good idea. This rule isn't applied at all, as you don't have any `ul` element with an `id` of `slider_reel`. You have `div` tags.

I'd try hiding the images beforehand, then running it:

```
$('#slider_reel img').hide();
// Innerfade code
```

Comment: I apologize I edited the code above. Following the example, there is no hide();? If I were to hide them, then it will run blank with no images? I apologize if I am wrong